# Generate Route URL in SignalR Hub

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I want to generate a route URL from within my SignalR Hub.

In a controller, I would do something like:

```
var u = new UrlHelper(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext);
string url = u.Action("Index", "Transfer", new { id = 27 });
```

Or:

```
var route = RedirectToAction("Index", "Transfer", new { id = 27 });
string url = Url.RouteUrl(route.RouteName, route.RouteValues)
```

But neither methods appear to be relevant within the hub.  Is there a mechanism I can use to construct the URL?

Comment: Could you explain the context of why you need this information inside the hub? Maybe there's an alternative way.

Comment: The function of the hub is to generate a report with a unique file id.  I wanted to keep the routing logic within the hub as I would need to 'manually' build the URL within the client.

Comment: Why not return the unique file id rather than the url AND build the link in the UI. Then your Hub is not wired to your View. Building the link in your View should be easy and if you ever needed it to be changed or use a different version then this is not built into the hub.

Comment: Thanks David, yes, this is certainly an option.  I was trying to use the hub more as an object factory for consumption by multiple client consumers, but adding the logic to the UI is certainly possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David pointed in his comment, I achieved the result with the same path.

My MVC view has a property:

```
public string ReportDownloadUrl { get; set; }
```

The hub method just returns the Uid of the file to be downloaded:

```
public ActionResult GetReport<T>(ReportModel pageModel)
{
    //generate the report and save to an internal server store
    var fileKey = GenerateReport(...);
    //return the unique file id
    return new JsonResult {Data = fileKey, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
}
```

Client side script invoking hub method and downloading the file by Url:

```
hubMethod(model, fileExtension)
.done(function (ret) {
    if (ret.Data) {
        var url = downloadUrl + "/" + ret.Data;
        DownloadURL(url);
    }
})

function DownloadURL(url) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("hiddenDownloader");

    if (iframe === null) {
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.id = "hiddenDownloader";
        iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }

    iframe.src = url;
}
```

Controller action for actual file download:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string id)
{
    //3 first characters of id are file extension in my case
    var format = id.Substring(0, 3);
    var fileFormat = (FileFormat)Enum.Parse(typeof(FileFormat), format, true);
    var file = (KeyValuePair<string, byte[]>)DataStore[id];


    return File(file.Value, fileFormat.ToDescription(), file.Key);
}
```

Hope it saves someone's time.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I ended up doing something similar (though not as tidy - I had hard-coded the URL in the client script!).  I have updated my code accordingly and it works perfectly.